# Ошибка DataBinding Android (Cannot inherit from final 'ru.uch.databinding.ItemDocScanTableBinding')

Tags: android, android-data-binding

Объясните почему может возникать ошибка **Cannot inherit from final 'ru.uch.databinding.ItemDocScanTableBinding'**
Точнее это не ошибка, а просто Android Studio в автоматически сгенерированом классе подчёркивыет его красной чертой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слой фрагмента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="modelDoc"
        type="ru.uch.viewModelUchMK.ViewModelDoc" />

    <variable
        name="myAdapter"
        type="ru.uch.adapterUchMK.AdapterList" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#888"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#888"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textColor"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#7fc342"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/column_name_color"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textSize"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/column_name_size"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDefect"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#7fc342"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/column_name_defect"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textGrey"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/column_name_grey"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCount"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#7fc342"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/column_name_count"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adapter="@{myAdapter}"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_doc_scan_table"/>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#888"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textEmpty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCountAll"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#7fc342"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@{String.valueOf(modelDoc.countAllBarDoc)}"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

И такая "беда" у всех классов автоматически созданных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите пожалуйста файл разметки фрагмента

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: попробуйте очистить проект и пересобрать, если не поможет, то сделайте из этого файла обратно макет не для биндинга - пересоберите - добавьте биндинг

Comment: Очистка и пересборка не помогла. Сейчас ещё заметил что у меня у абсолютно всех автоматически созданных классов такая ошибка. Я только недавно начал переводить свой проект на binding и не обращал на это внимания. Есть смысл переделывать макет, раз у всех такая беда?  Я добавил новую картинку в вопрос.

Comment: да нет, смысла переделывать нету я думаю, а как вы биндинг подключали?

Comment: В каком смысле как? 1. В макете сделал корневой слой, через контекстное меню. 2. Во фрагменте начал писать FragmentListBinding binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());, а классы создались по Alt+Enter. Как то так. Или что то другое имеется ввиду?

Comment: я имею ввиду как вы подключали в градле это все?

Comment: buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
Вот так

Comment: А если новый проект подключить к биндингу, он нормально будет работать?

Comment: Сейчас создал новый проект с 1 активити, после добавления DataBinding та же проблема.

Comment: уберите `dataBinding { enabled true }` из градла, у меня только с build_features и все ок

Comment: Забейте - это не мешает сборке проекта и работе приложения. Просто глюк анализатора из-за кодогенерации. Краснота в папке `build` и исходниках библиотек - обычное дело. Главное чтобы в вашем собственном коде было всё чисто.

Comment: К сожалению удаление dataBinding { enabled true } не помогло. Придется видимо оставить всё как есть. Благо на работу это никак не влияет. Но всё равно, внутренне эта ситуация вызывает отторжение.. :(

Comment: Если сильно возмущает - запостите багрепорт, пусть исправляют))) По моим ощущения одну из папок сгенерированных классов не добавили или не вовремя добавляют в sourceset. Из-за этого они видны компилятору только во время сборки. Я пробовал прописать её вручную и это избавляло от красноты, но потом забил и забыл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придется видимо оставить всё как есть. Благо на работу это никак не влияет. Но всё равно, внутренне эта ситуация вызывает отторжение.. :(